# .Add(null) would break my list<string>. I would like to add in a condition to replcae null with a string

Tags: c#, null

I ran into quite an interesting issue. In conclusion, I learned that `empty` and `null` are two different things.

I am currently creating a constructore that takes stores two `List<string>`s.

```
    public ValueList(List<string> firstList, List<string> secondList) {

        for (int i = 0; i < firstList.Count; i++) {

            // Checks for nulls.
            if(firstList[i] == null){
                _firstList.Add("null");
            }else if (secondList[i] == null){
                _secondList.Add("null");
            }else{
                _firstList.Add(firstList[i].ToString());
                _secondList.Add(secondList[i].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

There are times where this constructor would read Excel files, and in any blank square, the other script I use would parse in a `null` value. The `null` value would break my script entirely, and not `.Add()` anything.

So I tried to put in my null-check conditions. If that particular index is a null, then we add a `"null"` string.

However, the `null` continues to break my script.

I was wondering if there is a more elegant and fool-proof way to combat this issue? I think I have also tried `.Equals(null)` but that did not solve the issue at all.

Comment: `firstList[i]` is already a string.Why are you converting string to String again?

Comment: `"null"` is almost never what you want.  You should fix your code to handle nulls correctly; don't make the data wrong.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. first you clear _firstList, then iterate over it.

Comment: Why not just properly handle `null` and make it not break your script?

Comment: @L.B there are two lists - `_firstList` and `firstList`

Comment: @DStanley Aha, very nice naming.....

Comment: @l.b he is using a improper variable naming theme calling two separate vars the same name but different only by an _

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper logic would be

```
    for (int i = 0; i < firstList.Count; i++) {

        // Checks for nulls.
        if(firstList[i] == null){
            _firstList.Add("null");
        }
        else {
            _firstList.Add(firstList[i].ToString());
        } 

        if (secondList[i] == null){
            _secondList.Add("null");
        }
        else{
            _secondList.Add(secondList[i].ToString());
        }
    }
```

But you could just to a Linq projection:

```
_firstList = firstList.Select(s => s ?? "null").ToList();
_secondList = secondList.Select(s => s ?? "null").ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Since you *do* want to store `nulls` you just need to not call `ToString`:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < firstList.Count; i++) {
        _firstList.Add(firstList[i]);
        _secondList.Add(secondList[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Should this snippet replace my for-loop entirely?

Comment: @thegreencabbage yes, forget `for`. C# is not java. And you should handle your data properly and not let `null`s into your `List<string>` if you don't need them.

Comment: Hi D. Stanley. I would like to keep using the for-loop, as our devs would prefer the readability of it. I guess I have to take back my question as well. Is there any way for `List<string>` to store `null`s as well? I would like to the constructor to not alter anything.

Comment: Sure, just don't call `.ToString()` since it's already a string.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: What error do you get?  You should be able to insert `null` into a `List<string>`

Comment: Actually, never mind. It turns out I had a `.ToString()` in another method call outside of this example. Does `.ToString()` break `List<strings>` involving nulls?

Comment: Yes you cannot call `ToString` on a null reference.  If it's _already_ a string, though, then `ToString` is unnecessary.  If it's not a string then `value == null ? null : value.ToString()` is a common practice.

Comment: Ah I see.. Originally, I didn't have a `.ToString()` in my original method. Honestly, I learned two things: 1. `string.Empty` and `null` are two different things. 2. `null` cannot be used `.ToString()` in. I have removed all residual `.ToString()` in my other method calls. Hopefully nothing else breaks this script! Thank you SO much for the patience and help.